# undefined is not an object (evaluating '_reactNative.NavigationActions.reset')

Tags: react-native, splash-screen, reset

I have an error when I run this code.

```
componentDidMount() {
    setTimeout( () => {this.props.navigation.dispatch(NavigationActions.reset({
index: 0,
key: null,
actions: [NavigationActions.navigate('loginScreen')]}))} , 1000)
```

I used this in splashScreen I want to remove splashScreen after back from second screen

Answer (score 0):

You can use like this if you want to reset your navigation stack.

```
const resetAction = StackActions.reset({
                     index: 0,
                     actions:[NavigationActions.navigate({ routeName: 'ScreenName' })],
 });                                                
this.props.navigation.dispatch(resetAction);
```